# Oracle Inserting a row in a table only if a match found in some other table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, insert, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 3 tables in my database namely employees,students and Images

```
create table employees(id number primary key,name varchar2(100), address varchar2(100));
create table students(id number primary key,name varchar2(100),address varchar2(100));
create table Images (image_id number primary key,employee_id number,student_id number,image_name varchar2(100));

Insert into employees values (1,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into employees values (2,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into employees values (3,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into employees values (4,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into employees values (5,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');

Insert into students values (1,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into students values (2,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into students values (3,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into students values (4,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into students values (5,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');
Insert into students values (49,'asdfasd','asdfasdf');

Insert into Images(image_id,employee_id,image_name) values (1,5,'adsfasdfasdf');
Insert into Images(image_id,student_id,image_name) values (2,49,'asfasdfasdf');
```

Now, when Inserting a row into the Images table I should check whether the employee_id / Student_id is existed in the employees table/student table, If a match found then only I have to Insert else it should not.

I thought of adding two foreign keys on the images table as follows:

```
alter table images add constraint fk_employeeid foreign key(employee_id)
references employees(id);
alter table images add constraint fk_studentsid foreign key(student_id)
references students(id);
```

But, If I do so. It will not allow me to insert null values. How can I modify my design so that whenever I insert a row in images table either it should be an employee_id or an student_id.

If I created any confusion, here is the link for the sql fiddle,http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92d24/1/0

Comment: *It will not allow me to insert null values* No, it will certainly allow NULL values. See my answer.

Comment: have you tired  insert before trigger for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought of adding two foreign keys on the images table.
>
> But, If I do so. It will not allow me to insert null values.

You are wrong when you say the foreign key constraint won't allow NULL values. It will definitely allow the **NULL** values.

**Test case**

Let's add the **foreign key constraint** on the `IMAGES` table for the `employee_id` and `student_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE images ADD CONSTRAINT fk_emp FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES employees(ID);
ALTER TABLE images ADD CONSTRAINT fk_stu FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(ID);
```

Let's check the **INSERT** with `NULL` values:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,employee_id,image_name) VALUES (1,5,'adsfasdfasdf');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,student_id,image_name) VALUES (2,49,'asfasdfasdf');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,employee_id,image_name) VALUES (3,null,'adsfasdfasdf');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,student_id,image_name) VALUES (4,null,'asfasdfasdf');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM images;

  IMAGE_ID EMPLOYEE_ID STUDENT_ID IMAGE_NAME
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------------
         1           5            adsfasdfasdf
         2                     49 asfasdfasdf
         3                        adsfasdfasdf
         4                        asfasdfasdf

SQL>
```

Let's check the **foreign key constraint validation**:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,employee_id,image_name) VALUES (1,10,'adsfasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO Images(image_id,employee_id,image_name) VALUES (1,10,'adsfasdfasdf')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.SYS_C0010739) violated


SQL> INSERT INTO Images(image_id,student_id,image_name) VALUES (2,20,'asfasdfasdf');
INSERT INTO Images(image_id,student_id,image_name) VALUES (2,20,'asfasdfasdf')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.SYS_C0010739) violated


SQL>
```

So, everything works as per the design.

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints to `images` like you did. Add one more constraint:

```
alter table images add constraint chk_nulls 
  check (
    (employee_id is not null and student_id is null)
    or (employee_id is null and student_id is not null) 
    );
```

This way you cannot insert both nulls nor both not nulls for employee_id and student_id. And foreign keys are also checked.

Test:

```
insert into images values (1, 1, null, 'not important');      -- OK
insert into images values (2, null, null, 'not important');   -- error
insert into images values (3, 1, 1, 'not important');         -- error
insert into images values (4, null, 1, 'not important');      -- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the primary key in table images, and have as PK three columns (image_id, employee_id and student_id).

**Edit 1: Based on comment**

I think you planned in a wrong way the problem. If the images are for both, employees and students, you should have two tables, images_employees and images_students, with respectively foreign keys employee_id and student_id and of course an id for the image. 
But is there any sense to have a row like this?

```
id: 1 student_id: null image_name: 'something'
```

I don't think so... please explain more about the purpose of images table.

Comment: If I do so, I can not add null values into the Images table right. But I should have a null for employee_id if there is a value for student_id vice versa. Also I need to check whether the employee_id/student_id am going to Insert are there in the employees/student table. If a match found then only I should Insert.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the foreign keys, that is the correct approach.

But instead of inserting `NULL`'s, you should define an "unknown record" in your `EMPLOYEES` and `STUDENTS` tables (maybe with an id=-1, name='UNKNOWN'), and insert -1 into your `IMAGES` table.